# Cannot invoke std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, std

This code gives me error in VS2015 update 1:

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type
>   std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using std::cout;
class A
{
public:
    virtual void init()
    {
        cout << "A";
    };
};


class B
{
public:
    virtual void init()
    {
        cout << "B";
    };
};

class C : private A, private B
{

    std::function<void()> a_init = &A::init;
    std::function<void()> b_init = &B::init;
public:
    void call()
    {
        a_init();
        b_init();
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.call();
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas if that's VS compiler is buggy or my code?
**EDIT**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <functional>
class A
{
public:
    virtual void inita()
    {
        cout << "A";
    };
};


class B
{
public:
    virtual void initb()
    {
        cout << "B";
    };
};

class C : private virtual A, private virtual B
{

    /*std::function<void()> a_init = &A::init;
    std::function<void()> b_init = &B::init;*/
public:
    void call()
    {
        inita();
    }
};
```

Comment: It's your code. How do you expect to call `&A::init`?

Comment: @KerrekSB by invoking it with () ?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando On what instance of `A`?

Comment: @TartanLlama on the same instance I'm calling it in my edit. See my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to assign non-static member functions into a `std::function` taking no arguments. That cannot work, since non-static member functions have an implicit `this` parameter.

How to solve this depends on what you want to do. If you want to call the stored function on an arbitrary object supplied at call time, you'll need to change the `std::function` signature:

```
std::function<void(A*)> a_init = &A::init;

void call()
{
  a_init(this); // or some other object of type A on which you want to invoke it
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa978eb9037e69de)

If, on the other hand, you want to call it without arguments, you will have to *bind* an object of type `A` into the `std::function` at initialisation:

```
std::function<void()> a_init = std::bind(&A::init, this);

void call()
{
  a_init()
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52da451877e0fcdb)

Answer (score 1):

Change the function from `virtual` to `static` and the code will work. You need a specific instance of a class to call a non-static function.

On the other hand, if you wish to use non-static function, you can add the following constructor:

```
C(A &a, B &b)
{
    a_init = std::bind(&A::init, &a);
    b_init = std::bind(&B::init, &b);
}
```

and then use it in main like this:

```
A a;
B b;
C c(a, b);
c.call();
```

EDIT:

If public inheritance is acceptable option, then you can do it even simpler.

Constructor:

```
C()
{
    a_init = std::bind(&A::init, this);
    b_init = std::bind(&B::init, this);
}
```

Usage:

```
C c;
c.call();
```

Comment: Hi, surely inheriting from A means that I have access to that object, which is created during creation of C? It is enough to trace ctors of all those classes involved in creation of C to realize that ctor of class A and ctor of class B are being called. See my edit.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Well you would have access if you were to use public inheritance. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes, but you were saying: "You need a specific instance of a class to call a non-static function." which as I've shown we already have when inheriting.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando I know what you mean and you can access these objects. You can simply cast `this` pointer (while using private inheritance ) to appropriate parent type when calling `std::bind` and the code will compile. However, it does not give expected results. When I run it, it calls A::init twice. Not sure why, the reason is probably buried in implementation of `std::bind`. Btw, the other answer did not explain any of this either.

Comment: that's OK I appreciate your answer and time.